# Creating matrix with getting maximum of each row and column

Tags: algorithm, matrix, language-agnostic

I want to make the *minimum* matrix given the *max* of each row and column.

**Example:**

**Given:**

```
row_max = [50, 20]
col_max = [50, 20, 3]
```

**Result:**

```
array = [[50, 0, 0],
         [0, 20, 3]]
```

Comment: are you trying to produce the resulting maximums arrays given a matrix or to find a matrix that would produce two starting arrays? (or something else?)

Comment: @ti7 The second one

Comment: What is a (or the if only one exists) minimum matrix?

Comment: @E.Shcherbo A Matrix with maximum number of zero and minimum value for each element.

Comment: Why is the result not `[[50,0,3],[0,20,0]]`?

Comment: @Redu That is ok as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `maxColIndex` be column's index which contains maximum value within `col_max`:

```
col_max = [50, 20, 3] # maxColIndex = 0
```

Let `maxRowIndex` be row's index which contains maximum value within `row_max`:

```
row_max = [10, 50, 20, 5] # maxRowIndex = 1
```

So we have

```
    | 50 20  3 
 ------------- 
 10 |  ?  ?  ? 
 50 |  ?  ?  ? <- maxRowIndex 
 20 |  ?  ?  ?
  5 |  ?  ?  ?
       ^
  maxColIndex
```

Now our goal is to put as many `0` as possible. Please note, that if there are *same values* in both max and min rows collections (e.g. `50`, `20`) we can put just one value:

```
    | 50 20  3 
 ------------- 
 10 |  ?  ?  ? 
 50 | 50  ?  ? <- maxRowIndex 
 20 |  ? 20  ?
  5 |  ?  ?  ?
       ^
  maxColIndex
```

Now put all the rest `row_max` values into the `maxColIndex` column:

```
    | 50 20  3 
 ------------- 
 10 | 10  ?  ? 
 50 | 50  ?  ? <- maxRowIndex 
 20 |  ? 20  ?
  5 |  5  ?  ?
       ^
  maxColIndex
```

Finally, put all the rest `col_max` values into the `maxRowIndex` row:

```
    | 50 20  3 
 ------------- 
 10 | 10  ?  ? 
 50 | 50  ?  3 <- maxRowIndex 
 20 |  ? 20  ?
  5 |  5  ?  ?
       ^
  maxColIndex
```

All indexes are set, time to fill the unset items of the matrix

```
    | 50 20  3 
 ------------- 
 10 | 10  0  0 
 50 | 50  0  3 <- maxRowIndex 
 20 |  0 20  0
  5 |  5  0  0
       ^
  maxColIndex
```